# Inside a ttk Radiobutton, how to center the text? (anchor not working)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk, ttkwidgets

tkinker.ttk `justify`and`anchor` is not working for `ttk.Radiobutton`.

This is my code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

window = Tk()
style = ttk.Style()
sty = ttk.Style(window)
op=IntVar(master=window)
sty.configure("TRadiobutton", background="green",foreground="red", anchor="center",justify='center')
entry_0 = ttk.Radiobutton(window,text="text",value=1,variable=op,style="white.TRadiobutton")
entry_0.place(
    x=0,
    y=0,
    anchor="nw",
    width=150
)
mainloop()
```

This is what I get:

[image: Radio button on the left of a green rectangle]

This is what I except:

[image: Radio button in the middle of a green rectangle]

PS: I can use `anchor=center` in a tk widget.

Comment: Try using `padding = "90 0 80 0"` in style configure and remove `width = 150` .

Answer (score 0):

As for you at entry level. You cannot jump to the immediate level. You have to lean step by step. Here is a newbie tutorial:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

window = Tk()
style = ttk.Style()
sty = ttk.Style(window)
op=IntVar(master=window)
sty.configure("TRadiobutton", background="green",
              foreground="red", anchor="center",
              justify='center')

entry_0 = ttk.Radiobutton(window,text="text",value=1,variable=op,
                          style="white.TRadiobutton").pack(side = TOP)
 
mainloop()
```